# Cannot use tree addons on blender on mac

Tags: add-on

It has now been 3 hours that I'm searching and I cannot figure out why I get an error with the tree addons of blender :-( Someone can help please? 
Seems some people already had this problem and solved it, but It was on windows. :-/ [image]

Comment: This is a known issue for a couple years now. I've find a way to get rid of this error. I first add a bezier curve and then I can add a tree ! Then I simply delete the bezier curve and It works :-)